# Rename tag [attr] to [jquery-attr]

Tags: support, retag-request, clean-up

[attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attr) has 652 questions, of which only [104](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attr+-javascript+-jquery) are not also tagged [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) or [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript). The tag wiki says »This tag should be used for attribute related issues.« which is basically not saying anything. There is also [attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attributes), which isn't great, but I think most of these 104 would fit there.

So, I think the tag should be renamed to [jquery-attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-attr), the description should be changed and the 104 questionable questions need to be retagged.

Comment: Personally I think [jquery-attr] and [jquery-prop] are stupid and should both be subsumed into [jquery], while [attr] and [prop] should cease to exist altogether.

Comment: @BoltClock I could live with that :)